# How can i consolidate multiple rows into one row(string)

Tags: sql, join, sas

I have a table that has multiple rows for each TRIP. Every rows will have different flag value in different column. However, the value is always 'Y' or null. I want to consolidate or group all same TRIP group into one row and at the same time, the values of flag must be retained. Below is the example:
[image: Left table to right table]

As we can see, table on the left(Table A) is the original table with StaffNo, Trip and Doc as key initially. However, what i want is to remove StaffNo and Doc from the table to become the one on the right(Table B).

At table A(Left).Notice the trip.
I want to remove Doc and StaffNo from Table A but retain the Flag value
look at row number 1 to 3 at table A. Compare the flag value at this 3 rows to table B row 1.

As we can see, I want the flag value from multiple rows that belong to the same trip to be consolidated to only 1 row.

Is there a way or workaround for this?

Comment: Why did you include SQL tag?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the UPDATE statement to collapse non-missing values across rows. The UPDATE statement wants a master and transaction dataset. For this problem you can use your data for both.

```
data want ;
  update have(obs=0) have ;
  by trip ;
  keep trip flag: ;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom. That does exactly what i wanted to do. Thanks Tom!
And for the question of why SQL tag, thats because i have been thinking to use SQL to solve it instead of SAS Datastep but you saved me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use sql, group trip and max(flag), letter is larger than missing value.

```
proc sql;
   select trip,max(flagA) as flagA,max(flagB) as flagB,max(flagC) as flagC,max(flagD) as flagD from have group by trip;
quit;
```